# What grammar term corresponds to N' in X-bar theory?

Tags: terminology, x-bar-theory

The core idea of X-bar theory is that it has what is called 'bar-level projection' or 'intermediate projection', which is normally represented by X'. And X represents any of the categories N, V, Adj, Adv, P, etc.

In an NP, X' is N'. The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language calls N' **nominal** while calling V' **VP**, as follows:

[image]

Is there any reason why they don't call N' NP just as they call V' VP?

Is term 'nominal' referring to N' well received by modern linguists? Or is there any other (better) term for N'?

Comment: That looks like very eclectic terminology. V' should not be called VP.

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't know what's wrong with calling _analysed the issues_ a VP.

Comment: In isolation it's a VP, but in "carefully analysed the issues" its a V'.

Comment: The distinction only matters in bar-room discussions.

Comment: @jlawler Hope that's not X-bar room you're talking about.

Comment: If you doubt CGEL's syntax, chuck it away and get another textbook.

Comment: @BillJ Even after almost two decades from its publication, CGEL is still the best grammar out there. That doesn't mean it's perfect. No grammar is. And I'm not doubting its syntax. I'm trying to understand it.